# Is it necessary to use the keyword "this" to distinguish uppercase and lowercase?

Tags: c#

1. Is it necessary to use the keyword "this" when I use uppercase(Name) and lowercase(name)?
2. Is it necessary to use ": this()" in my example? When should I use ": this()"?

My example:

```
namespace SharedCode
{
  public class Friendslist : IState
  {
    public struct MyContainer
    {
      public string Name;
      public string Firstname;
      public int Phonenumber;

      public MyContainer(string name, string firstname, int phonenumber)
           : this()
      {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Firstname = firstname;
        this.Phonenumber = phonenumber;
      }

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: No, it's just a convention to avoid clashes if the names exactly matched.

You should use `this()` if you want to invoke the constructor because it does something. In this case, you have an implicitly defined constructor which does nothing so calling `this()` does nothing.

Comment: Observation: `struct` is a bad choice for this - it *will* hurt you. If you don't know exactly why you're using `struct`, you should probably use `class` instead

Comment: @JeffFoster it doesn't quite do "nothing" - since this is a `struct` this achieves definite assignment of the fields, making them readable; however, this isn't a requirement in this example, so it is *redundant* - but it isn't "nothing"

Comment: Well, TIL, thank you!

For example, if `MyContainer` didn't initialize `Name` then not calling `this()` would result in a  compiler error because not all fields would be initialized. Calling `this()` explicitly would fix it.

Comment: Just FYI, it is a very bad idea to have variable names which are differentiated only by case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Is it necessary to use the keyword "this" when I use uppercase(Name) and lowercase(name)?

No. C# is case-sensitive.

If you had fields or properties which had the same names as parameters, then you would need to use `this.` to disambiguate between the two:

```
struct Foo
{
    private int bar;
    public Foo(int bar)
    {
        this.bar = bar;
    }
}
```

> 2. Is it necessary to use ": this()" in my example? When should I use ": this()"?

No.

Structs are a slightly odd case here -- you need to assign to every field before a struct constructor returns. However, a struct always has a compiler-generated parameterless constructor which initialises all fields to their default values.

Therefore, either your struct constructor needs to explicitly assign to every field (as yours does), or you can delegate to the parameterless constructor to initialise all fields to their default value and then just set some of the fields.

The story is different with classes: you don't need to assign to every field before a constructor returns. Therefore, you can only call `this()` if you have an explicit parameterless constructor, and you *should* only call it when you want to explicitly call that parameterless constructor for some reason.

Comment: "Structs are a slightly odd case here -- you need to assign to every field before a struct constructor returns." What should I change in my example if I don't use structs? I use the struct to create a list: public List<MyContainer> FriendsList = new List<MyContainer>(); FriendsList.Add(new MyContainer(FriendName, FriendFirstname, FriendPhonenumber));

Comment: @Bill_Johnson77 The general advice is to use a class unless you need a struct. If you change `Employee` to be a class, then you'll notice that the `: this()` is a compiler error, since there's no parameterless constructor (and the compiler isn't generating one). You'll probably want to remove this `: this()` call, rather than adding your own parameterless constructor

Comment: "The general advice is to use a class unless you need a struct." The problem is that my struct MyContainer is right now located in the public class Friendslist where I call the struct sometimes. Should I create another class for MyContainer where there is no other code except the code for MyContainer? How should the class look like and how should I call it in the Friendslist class?

Comment: @Bill_Johnson77 I don't follow your (very brief) description, but replace the `public struct MyContainer` with `public class MyContainer` to turn it into a class

Comment: I meant is it necessary(or better) to create two classes(two .cs files) in my project or should I try to put everything in only one class? For example: Should I create a class named MyContainer.cs where I only put the code that I used in my struct and create a second class named Friendslist.cs where I only call and use public class MyContainer?

Comment: @Bill_Johnson77 There's no simple answer to questions like that -- the whole skill of programming comes from making the best judgement calls in unclear cases. Either will work, do the one which is most maintaintable for you

Answer (score 4):

No, you should use `this` only when the arguments in the constructor have the same name with the properties in the class.

Answer (score 1):

Your `this()` is useless in this case. But you can use it for example to set a default
or calculated value.

So you can create a constructor like this (from MS-documentation):

```
public Employee(int weeklySalary, int numberOfWeeks)
: this(weeklySalary * numberOfWeeks)
{
}

public Employee(int annualSalary)
{
    Salary = annualSalary;
}
```

The const with the `this()` would call the second constructor so the Salary would be set.

If your code would look like following, you have to use the `this` in front of the fields (or properties if you have some):

```
class Employee
{
    string name;

    public Employee(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: "you have to use the this in front of the properties:" - the code shown *doesn't have any properties* - it has fields

Comment: How can I call Employee? Are there two possibilities to call it? public Employee(int weeklySalary, int numberOfWeeks)
: this(weeklySalary * numberOfWeeks)
{
}

Comment: I added a second const which should help. You would have another const which is called from the `this()`.